# Server login fail

Tags: linux, ssh

When I login in my server using ssh, it shows me a message with the number of failed logins since the last sucessfull login. Currently I have this:

```
Last failed login: Wed Jan 28 17:54:17 EST 2015 from 103.41.124.30 on ssh:notty
There were 1125 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
```

My question is: is this normal?

Also currently I'm using an ssh key for login. Is there anything more I can do to protect my server?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not 'normal', but within the realm of being targetted. Check your logs for ssh login attempts. It looks like a bruteforce password attempt with your username. Please make sure ssh is disabled for root. And I hope you have a strong password. => actually, if you are using a key/cert to login, you should disable ssh logins with passwords, unless you want to leave that there to misguide the attacker.

When you look at the ssh attempts in the log, if you are lucky, you can figure out who's trying to mess with you. But it might just be another generic botnet attack :-(

Comment: You may also want to ensure you have a three strikes your out rule for a password policy to prevent people from grinding the server if it's public

Comment: Some sysadmins/devs/operators find that very annoying, feel free to ask my colleagues ;-)

Comment: I know those guys.  lol

Comment: Thanks for the idea of the ssh logs. It's quite funny to see it's usrname attempts to login

Comment: I'm glad to hear it makes you smile :-) Botnets often use low frequency attempts these day, which is at odds with brute force password guessing, but I guess it works for them. Search the web for 'hail mary cloud' :-)

Comment: From what I see, there where two bots. One was trying random usernames but with a low frequency of attempts, and another one using root as username and with a high frequency

Comment: Yes, that's why most distros and BSD flavors turn off ssh access for the root account. I strongly recommend you do the same. But don't forget to give sudo rights to a sysadmin account first :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the account you are using is named root (or something else rather common) and sshd is exposed to the internet, yes this within the normal range.

You say you are using an ssh key for login. Is password authentication permitted? You could disable it. (If the account is root consider `PermitRootLogin without-password`.) Also, install `fail2ban`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend change if you are using default weird `22` port. If you dont have a firewall, you must have one. I use csf in my environment and it has some block rules for brute force attackers.

Comment: Changing the default port is not much of a defense, and more hassle than it's worth. There's plenty of bots that also port scan and figure out where your sshd daemon lives.

Comment: Since i was using default port, my firewall blocking over 500 failed ssh login ips per day. Now i have 0 failed ssh login in my environment. Thats why i shared my experience.

Comment: Ouch, thank you for sharing. I guess I've been luckier with IP address range/datacenter/cloud provider. Also I guess we get more targetted attacks because of big fat mailservers & userbase.